# How to create a 2D array based on the length passed to an array

Tags: go

```
func matrix(n int) {
  var result [n][n]int //Does not work
  fmt.Println(result)
}
```

How to create a 2D array based on the length passed to an array; n is the length of the array.

Comment: Go doesn't have 2D arrays. The closest you can get is arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)
>
> An array is a numbered sequence of elements of a single type, called
>   the element type. The number of elements is called the length and is
>   never negative.
>
> ```
> ArrayType   = "[" ArrayLength "]" ElementType .
> ArrayLength = Expression .
> ElementType = Type .
> ```
>
> The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a
>   non-negative constant representable by a value of type int. The length
>   of array a can be discovered using the built-in function len. The
>   elements can be addressed by integer indices 0 through len(a)-1. Array
>   types are always one-dimensional but may be composed to form
>   multi-dimensional types.

---

> The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a
>   non-negative constant representable by a value of type int.

The size of an array is fixed at compile-time.

---

Use a slice instead.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func matrix(n int) [][]int {
    m := make([][]int, n)
    for i := range m {
        m[i] = make([]int, n)
    }
    return m
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(matrix(3))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/D1MHmm5KCht

Output:

```
[[0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]]
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate the further dimensions individually, like so:

```
func matrix(n int) {
    var result = make([][]int, n)
    for i := range result {
        result[i] = make([]int, n)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

With an actual array with fixed dimensions known at compile-time, you can do something like:

```
var result [5][5]int
```

but this is not the case you have.